# startActivityForResult(Intent, int) what is the purpose of the integer argument

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following a tutorial that uses "startActivityForResult" function. I know why this function is used and if we want to use the returned data, we use onActivityResult() function. The thing that I wana know is, why do we pass an Integer to startActivityForResult() function? And where is it used?

Thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Activity that you're starting finished, that second argument is passed to the method `onActivityResult()` of the calling Activity. This is to distinguish different results from one another.

You may have a case where an Activity needs to call several others for results, and by specifying a unique `int` for each of them, you can determine the correct thing to do when you get a result.

**Edit:** Here's an example.

Suppose you have a screen (Activity A) where you choose a picture from your gallery, and you choose a friend to send it to. You'll start an activity to pick a picture from the gallery on a button click, and maybe you also have a "friend picker" activity which you can also start from Activity A.

You want both of those activities to return the data the user selected. `onActivityResult()` will get called on Activity A when the user finishes with the two activities described above. By specifying the `requestCode` for `startActivityForResult()` for the gallery activity, and your "friend picker", you know what to do in `onActivityResult()`.

Also, note that you don't need a complicated scheme for `requestCode`. You could just pass in the values `1` and `2` for the gallery and friend picker, respectively.

Comment: can you please explain by an example "You may have a case where an Activity calls several others for results"..

Comment: @Alfred James: let's say you have some activity which need in some point to launch the camera and get the resulting image, and beside that in some point need to raise activity to select image from gallery.   then you will start each one of them with a diffrent unique code. (for example the camera would be "1" and gallery "2")  with this code you will know in the onActivityResult() callback where your current result from, and by that - how to handle the data intent

Answer (score 1):

It is to differentiate between different results.  You might use different intents to start each `Activity` and typically you have constants like this:

```
ACTIVITY_RESULT_INTENT_1 = 1
ACTIVITY_RESULT_INTENT_2 = 2
```

So if you passed one of these into `startActivityForResult()`, then it will also return these request codes to allow you to use whatever logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

From [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

> If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

So, its for your own benefit. Just set a code - if you want, use an ENUM to set some proper return values. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

> requestCode   If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.